# Font does not change color upon select

Tags: css, fonts, colors

Please check out my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zzh0ym2m/1/

Once I click on a menu button "Home", "Settings", and so on, the font should be changing to white, but it doesn't. I cannot figure out where the error is located, after trying to change stuff around. It should be turning white:

```
.topmenu-selectedblue {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#78b1ff, #4881dc)
}
.topmenu-selectedred {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff8476, #dc5348)
}
.topmenu-selectedpurple {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#b479ff, #854ade)
}
.topmenu-selectedgreen {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9dd592, #649f5a)
}
.topmenu-selectedorange {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fdc652, #dba439)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this

```
.topmenu-ul > li a {
    color: #e6e6e6;
    font-size: .7rem;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px
}
```

is overriding any other settings.

So you need to address that..perhaps with

```
.topmenu-ul > [class*=topmenu-selected] > a{
    color: #fff;
}
```

That said, there is some repetition and very specific selectors in your CSS that could be tidied up that might make it simpler.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zzh0ym2m/4/)

Comment: Thanks, that's true and it will be the next step, after I get it working the way I want. Still learning CSS, that's why I am trying to re-create things my own way, just for learning purposes :)